# The double slit experiment and classical mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, double-slit-experiment, thought-experiment

As I understand, it is perfectly possible to explain the standard double slit experiment with a laser beam using only classical physics.

On the other hand, this experiment is one of those experiments which is mentioned the most when quantum theory is introduced. So at what point of the experiment -- or through which variation -- does quantum theory come in where classical physics fails ?

Comment: There are many double slit experiments. Can you explain what you mean by "the standard double slit experiment?" Likewise what is the "classical optics of point particles." Seems a bit contradictory to me... "classical optics" in my mind is the about behavior of electromagnetic waves and I just don't see what it could have to do with point particles.

Comment: Your starting assumption is wrong. There is no way to explain the double-slit experiment using only classical physics. Where did you read it?

Comment: @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 - to be fair, classical waves (light, water, ...) describe the double slit experiments nicely. The issue is when 'particles' were used and the result was still the same.

Comment: @JonCuster Exactly right... hence why I asked for clarification. OP could have easily been talking about the double slit experiment with a laser. But they said it could be described by "classical optics of point particles" and I don't see what point particles have to do with E+M applied to electromagnetic waves.

Comment: Yup, when waves and particles become the same thing is when people think it gets weird. Then, hopefully, an epiphany occurs and it is all good again...

Comment: @AXensen: I adapted my question.

Comment: @JonCuster When the question refers to the double slit experiment in the context of the introduction of quantum theory, it is not referring to the classical Young's experiment demonstrating the wave nature of light, but to experiments where single particles are detected. Now, the formulation of the question is more clear, and Andrew's answer clearly explains the difference of regime.

Comment: Classically, waves (like water) form an interference pattern through two slits of appropriate size. It's just waves combining. QM version is like shooting bullets one at a time at the slits (even with a large time gap, one per day, say), and each one either passes through or ricochets randomly, and leaves a hole at the target - and then after couple of hundred bullets, it becomes apparent that the bullet holes form a striped pattern. (except in the real experiment, the bullets are individual photons, or electrons, or atoms, or even molecules). Classically this makes no sense.

Answer (score 6):

If you shine a laser **with many photons** into two slits and observe the diffraction pattern on a screen, then you can indeed use Maxwell's equations (with no quantum theory) to explain the result.

However, "The Double Slit" experiment talked about in quantum mechanics involves sending **individual particles** through the slits, and observing the distribution of particles after repeating this experiment many times. In the case of light, you would be sending individual photons through the apparatus (as Solomon Slaw points out in the comments, this amounts to using a laser with a very low intensity, and this experiment has been done with lots of different types of particles, including [buckyballs](https://www.nature.com/articles/nnano.2012.34)). After many repetitions of this single photon experiment, you would see the same diffraction pattern appear.

How do individual particles "know" to collectively create a statistical distribution derived from the interference of paths going through both slits, when the particles can be sent through the slit one at a time and never interact? This is the key mystery of the quantum double slit experiment.

Comment: @THC, The TLDR version is, You can take a classical double-slit apparatus and "turn down" the intensity of the laser beam until you are sure that there is virtually no chance of ever having more than one photon in the box at a time, and you still will get the same diffraction pattern. (This is not a thought experiment. It's actually been shown.)

Comment: It’s an interference pattern, not a diffraction pattern. Though the majority of pop sci animations leave the proper diffraction pattern out when which way information is available, which only serves to decrease understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Double slit experiment can be discussed for photons or electrons (which usually stand for more general case of bosons and fermions.) While the experiment looks superficially similar for both, what is important/accentuated is not the same.

**Double slit experiment with photons**
Photons are quanta of electromagnetic radiation. Even classical electromagnetic radiation is waves, which exhibit typical wave phenomena, such as *diffraction* an *interference*. These can be observed using double slit experiment and do not require quantum description.

However, at very low light intensities, we can make the interference pattern disappear by trying to observe which slit the light passes through. This proves that light really consists of discrete quanta (i.e., exhibits particle nature.)

**Double slit experiment with electrons**
Electrons are classically thought of as particles, i.e., they cannot simultaneously pass through two slits - particle trajectory passes either through one slit or through the other. However, quantum electrons are described by a Schrödinger equation, which is a wave equation. They then behave as waves and exhibit diffraction and interference, which for them is the signature of quantum behavior.

Thus, *the double slit experiment proves wave-particle duality, but this proof obviously goes in different directions for electrons and photons (classically particles and waves respectively.)*

Answer (score 0):

The double slit experiment is a great mystery and one that we can never understand ..... OK how many times have we heard that! Actually if one considers virtual fields i.e. the excited electron in a light source which is already interacting with the EM field the mystery can be easily explained away! Same for the electron version of the double slit ... the anode is excited with a high voltage/temperature, excited electrons are already interacting with the EM field virtually before their emission .... it would be impossible for excited electrons not to be interacting with the EM field.

But we have legions (since 1900s) of thousands of amateur and professional physicists ... and for most of the professionals the classic theory is just fine for their needs!  It seems as though it's the amateur physicists that are most caught up in the sexy headlines ... quantum teleportation .... faster than light communication ... an electron particle that splits into 2 .... blah blah blah .... its makes for great headlines (unfortunately a lot of professional physicists are behind these).  The truth is the double slit proved the wave nature of light .... but more importantly the wave nature of EM fields.

The photon is guided/forced on its path by the EM field, the field being active a long time with the excited electron.  Every photon is doing its own thing, superimposing itself in the EM field.  There is no big reward to humanity (like fusion or fission) to solving the DSE ... it is an old experiment from the 1900s .... lets all just move on.