Why in the experiment of double slits, in case of radiation of wavelength of red light, we can observe an envelop of the minimum?
I have made an experiment in which i have to measure the intensity of the light generated by an $\text{He-Ne}$ laser, in the case of two slits, I pretend to observe an interference lattice.
I have to compute the coefficient of visibility for the experimental data.
In the lattice I have observed  an envelop of the minimum, how can I explain this?

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/798891/path-lengths-in-the-dual-slit-experiment-and-the-speed-of-light/798910#798910

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/787452/do-photons-behave-like-particles-when-observed-on-the-double-slit-experiment/787461#787461

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/769987/the-double-slit-experiment-and-classical-mechanics/770029#770029
